# Angular 2 Turn form control into form group later

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form array with a control called "foreground" which is null to start with:

```
(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rooms')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
                id: [element.id, [Validators.required]],
                background: null,
                foreground: null,
            }));
```

But how can I turn it onto a form group with fields under it later on? I tried this:

```
room.controls.foreground(this.fBuilder.group({
                foregroundImageID: [null, [Validators.required]],
                foregroundImagePath: [null, [Validators.required]],
                foregroundXPosition: [null, [Validators.required]],
                foregroundYPosition: [null, [Validators.required]]
            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like below:

```js
(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rooms')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
    id: [element.id, [Validators.required]],
    background: null,
    foreground: null
}));
```

Now `SetControl` like this-

```js
this.myForm.controls.rooms['controls'][0].setControl('foreground', this.fBuilder.group({
      foregroundImageID: [null, [Validators.required]],
      foregroundImagePath: [null, [Validators.required]],
      foregroundXPosition: [null, [Validators.required]],
      foregroundYPosition: [null, [Validators.required]]
}));
```

**Note:** `setControl` replaces the existing control. [learn more about setControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setcontrol)

Comment: Also how would I set that "foreground" back to null later on?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Do you how how would I set that "foreground" back to null later on? :)

Comment: You can just remove the control like- `this.myForm.controls.rooms['controls'][0].removeControl('foreground')`

Comment: Hmm I got an error of "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Build your form like this

```
(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rooms')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
                id: [element.id, [Validators.required]],
                background: null,
                foreground: this.fBuilder.array([]),
            }));
```

Here Now foreground working as Array, With that you can push elememts into foreground

Comment: Thanks but it has to start as null to begin with. I can't start with it being an array.

Comment: try with setControl https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#setControl